# Create a web chat with WebSockets

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I'm trying to create a web chat, currently limited to two users, using JavaScript and PHP WebSockets, but I can't connect client and server. I have never used WebSockets before.

I usually get this error from PHP: Warning: socket_bind(): Unable to bind address [xxx]. I tried to change the port number, but i can't fix.

PS: I'm working with XAMPP

Here's what i tried:

script.js (client):

```
//WebSocket connection
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:1234');

// WebSocket event menagement
socket.onopen = function() {
    console.log('Connessione WebSocket stabilita.');
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    const message = JSON.parse(event.data);
    displayMessage(message);
};

socket.onclose = function() {
    console.log('Socket connection closed.');
};


//Sending messages
document.getElementById('chat-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input');
    const message = {
        text: messageInput.value
    };
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
    messageInput.value = '';
});

// Display messages
function displayMessage(message) {
    const chatMessages = document.getElementById('chat-messages');
    const messageElement = document.createElement('div');
    messageElement.textContent = message.text;
    chatMessages.appendChild(messageElement);
    chatMessages.scrollTop = chatMessages.scrollHeight;
}
```

server.php (server):

```
<?php
    //WebSocket Initializing
    $host = 'localhost';
    $port = 1234;

    // Create socket
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    if ($socket === false) {
        echo "Impossibile creare il socket: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
        exit;
    }

    // Binding socket
    $result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port);
    if ($result === false) {
        echo "Can't bind socket: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
        exit;
    }

    // Ascolto del socket
    $result = socket_listen($socket);
    if ($result === false) {
        echo "Can't read socket: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
        exit;
    }

    // Accettazione delle connessioni WebSocket
    $clientSocket = socket_accept($socket);
    if ($clientSocket === false) {
        echo "Client not connected: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
        exit;
    }

    $message = array('text' => 'Welcome to chat!');
    socket_write($clientSocket, json_encode($message));


    // Message menagement
    while (true) {
        // Verify connection before reading Socket

        /*
        $socketStatus = stream_get_meta_data($clientSocket);
        if ($socketStatus['timed_out'] || !$socketStatus['eof']) {
            // Connection closed
            break;
        }
        */

        $clientMessage = socket_read($clientSocket, 1024);
        if ($clientMessage === false) {
            echo "Can't read socket: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($clientSocket));
            break;
        }

        // Processing

        // Send messagen to client
        socket_write($clientSocket, $clientMessage);
    }



    // Socket close
    socket_close($clientSocket);
    socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Comment: try `$host = '127.0.0.1';`

Comment: Use a ready made websocket server such as Ratchet.

Comment: @Kazz 
I tried that too, but it doesn't work as "localhost" resolves to 127.0.0.1

Comment: i believe this is low level, there is no DNS resolving involved at all at `socket_bind`, therefore using "localhost" is invalid address